# When embedding JSON in a Forge WorkItem, what specifies the name of the json file?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm following along [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/), under Additional notes, Input arguments:Embedded JSON, as well as the CountItApp code [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-countdeletewalls-revit) (which I assumed was what was being referenced by the first link, but maybe that is a poor assumption?)

In any case, I see that in [CountItApp\Main.cs](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-countdeletewalls-revit/blob/346888edcd4b1f8f5b03fa7c482defafff7525ea/CountItApp/Main.cs#L146), it is looking for a file called "params.json", but I'm having trouble locating where that name was specified when submitting the WorkItem. Is embedded JSON always called params.json, or is it specified somewhere that I'm missing? Or does it [use the value specified in the "post" for the Activity](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/activities-POST/) (per the Activity example for InventorParams at that link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the params.json is defined on the Activity. When you call the Workitem, the embedded JSON is passed as that parameter and saved with the name defined.